# PDO return empty result o last result Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Please, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

```
$unir = "";

$equxflo = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT idequipo, CONCAT(equipo.nombre,' ',equipo.modelo,' ',equipo.marca,' ',equipo.serieplaca) AS flota FROM equipo WHERE idusuario = '$idu' ORDER BY idequipo DESC");    
$equxflo->execute();
while($row = $equxflo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    print_r($row); //show me all the array
    $ht = $row['flota'];
    $ie = $row['idequipo'];
    $unir = "["."'"."$ht"."'".","."$ie"."]".",";
}
print_r($unir); //show me only la last data
```

Comment: `$idu` isn't set in this, please check it with `var_dump($idu);` before assigning it in the query.

Comment: Use prepared statements when you have outside input

Comment: Use parameter binding.

Comment: Firstly, you're not preparing anything and if you don't want to do that, then you're using too many functions to achieve the same result. you can drop the `->prepare` and `execute()` by a mere `->query()`.

Comment: hello man $idu = 2; for example but y have the same problem :(

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Hello Fred y change for ->query() but return the last data :( y have 3 results but show 1 result only the last result :(

Comment: If you only want the last result, then why do you do `ORDER BY idequipo ASC` instead of `ORDER by  idequipo ASC LIMIT 1`?

Comment: @JhoNerVega With this `$unir = "["."'"."$ht"."'".","."$ie"."]".",";`, are you trying to put the data as an array and push it to `$unir` in each iteration?

Comment: Hi Charlotte I have 3 results in my DB and I need to show the 3 results, if there are 1000 results y my DB y need to show the 1000 results, but show me only the last result :(

Comment: @RajdeepPaul for example I like the show in $unir  this  ['a',3],['a',2],['a',1], but only show ['a',1], I don't now what wrong ? :(

Comment: You are _overwriting_ the value of `$unir` in each loop iteration – so of course only the last one “survives” in the end. You would need to concatenate – `$unir .= …`. But this rather looks like you are trying to generate JSON? If that’s the case: Don’t do that “manually” – create the appropriate data structure, and then use `json_encode`.

Comment: @JhoNerVega I've given an answer. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because of this line:

```
$unir = "["."'"."$ht"."'".","."$ie"."]".",";
     ^ missing concatenation operator
```

> for example I like the show in $unir this ['a',3],['a',2],['a',1], but only show ['a',1] ...

Based on your requirement, do this:

```
$unir = "";

$equxflo = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT idequipo, CONCAT(equipo.nombre,' ',equipo.modelo,' ',equipo.marca,' ',equipo.serieplaca) AS flota FROM equipo WHERE idusuario = :idu ORDER BY idequipo DESC");
$equxflo->bindParam(":idu", $idu);

if ($equxflo->execute()) {
    while ($row = $equxflo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $ht = $row['flota'];
        $ie = $row['idequipo'];
        $unir .= "['" . $ht . "'," . $ie . "],";
    }
    print_r($unir);
}
```

**Better Solution:**

A better solution would be to declare `$unir` as an array and put data in a temporary array and push it to `$unir` array in each iteration, like this:

```
$unir = array();

$equxflo = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT idequipo, CONCAT(equipo.nombre,' ',equipo.modelo,' ',equipo.marca,' ',equipo.serieplaca) AS flota FROM equipo WHERE idusuario = :idu ORDER BY idequipo DESC");
$equxflo->bindParam(':idu', $idu);

if ($equxflo->execute()) {
    while ($row = $equxflo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $tmp_array = array($row['flota'], $row['idequipo']);
        $unir[] = $tmp_array;
    }
    print_r($unir);
}
```

Comment: thanks but in this $equxflo->bind_param(':idu', $idu); remove the subscript and the solution: $equxflo->bindparam(':idu', $idu); thanks for your help :D

Comment: @JhoNerVega oops, missed that. Thanks for pointing that out. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recode it in this manner, notice the [`bindParam`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) method. Also you are overwriting the result set per every iteration. I added a variable `$final_result[]` which stores the results:

```
$equxflo = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT idequipo,
                                    CONCAT(
                                           equipo.nombre,' ',
                                           equipo.modelo,' ',
                                           equipo.marca,' ',
                                           equipo.serieplaca) AS flota
                             FROM equipo
                             WHERE idusuario = :idu
                             ORDER BY idequipo DESC
                              ");
$equxflo->bindParam(":idu", $idu);

if ($equxflo->execute()) {
    $final_result = array();
    while ($row = $equxflo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        print_r($row); //show me all the array
        $ht = $row['flota'];
        $ie = $row['idequipo'];

        // I DONT UNDERSTAND WHAT YOU ARE DOING WITH $unir
        // IS IT JSON? IS IT AN ARRAY? ...EXPLAIN
        $unir = "[" . "'" . "$ht" . "'" . "," . "$ie" . "]" . ",";

        $final_result[] = $row;  // <-- YOU MISSED THIS
    }
    print_r($final_result); //shows all result
    print_r(json_encode($final_result)); //shows result in JSON
    print_r(end($final_result)); //show only last result set
}
```

Comment: @CodeGogie I've type your code, It's the same problem :( but thanks for your help :(

Comment: Can you tell me what the problem is you are having? I guess you werent being specific in your initial question.

Comment: check out my updated answer. Look at the variable `$final_result[]`. Was that your problem?

Comment: I think what would help us understand your problem is if you tell us what your goal is? What result are you expecting?

Comment: @CodeGodie: I prefer binding like this: `$equxflo->execute(array(':idu' => $idu));` It's one less line of code and does the same